# Is there an asyncio-friendly version for presto

Tags: python, presto, trino, aiopg

I know that there exists a package called `aiopg` for working with Postgresql in `asyncio`-friendly connections. Is there a similar version/package for Presto? I'm trying to implement concurrency for querying in Presto connections in Python.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How many concurrent queries to you expect to send to Presto from your Python app?

Comment: Hi @PiotrFindeisen! Thanks for taking the time to respond. I'm looking at ~5 Presto-connection memory intensive queries. I was hoping to gather these along with my Postgres-connection queries (~15 count) and run them in one `asyncio` loop (using their respective connections). The goal would be that if each query takes at least 5 mins or greater to complete, then at least at one point, early in the loop, all the queries would have been sent (to save time). But let me know if you have other suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presto Python API does not provide `asyncio` integration, so you need to treat it as any other blocking IO in `asyncio` world.

I am not familiar with `asyncio`, but [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) looks like the way to do this.

Since you're not running thousands of concurrent queries (which wouldn't make sense in Presto anyway), this isn't going to hurt performance of your application.

I recommend that you also create a feature request in https://github.com/prestosql/python-client/issues/new (this is a new repo, so you can get very low, cool issue number).